# Evaluate $\sum_{i=t'}^{s'-1} \delta (1-\delta)^{2(s'-1-i)}$ as $\delta \to 0$.

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Suppose
$$
\delta = \frac{s-t}{s'-t'}
$$
where $s,t$ are fixed. Evaluate 
$$\sum_{i=t'}^{s'-1} \delta (1-\delta)^{2(s'-1-i)}
$$
as $\delta \to 0$. Is there even such a limit?

I think that $\delta \to 0$ implies $s'-t' \to \infty$. So it would seem to follow that the limit should include some form of the exponential, $e^{-x}$, due to the familiar limit. But I haven't made further progress. Is there a closed form solution to this?

Comment: It is actually a the sum of a geometric sequence so you can compute the closed form, then evaluate the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the sum by $A_\delta$, by letting $j = i - t'$, we have
\begin{align*}
A = & \sum_{j = 0}^{s' - t' - 1}\delta(1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t' - 1 - j)} \\
= &\delta (1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t' - 1)} \sum_{j = 0}^{s' - t' - 1}(1- \delta)^{-2j} \\
= & \delta(1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t' - 1)} \frac{(1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t')} - 1}{(1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t')} - (1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t' - 1)}} \\
= & \frac{(1 - \delta)^{2(s' - t')} - 1}{\delta - 2} \\
= & \frac{[(1 - \delta)^{1/\delta}]^{2(s - t)} - 1}{\delta - 2} \\
\to & -\frac{\exp(-2(s - t)) - 1}{2}
\end{align*}
as $\delta \to 0$, where we used the fact
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} (1 - \delta)^{1/\delta} = \exp(-1).$$

Comment: How did you achieve the $\delta-2$ below?

Comment: @mathjacks just do the algebra simplification.